# How to change the type of an input tag when clicking on a button?

Tags: javascript, solid-js

I am currently creating my app login form in solid-js. I created a button that is displayed when a value is entered in the password field and I would like that when the user clicks on this button, the input of this field changes from type `password` to type `name` . Here is my code:

```
export default function Login() {
  const [hidden, setHidden] = createSignal("");
  const type = (setHidden ? 'password' : 'name' )
  function toggle() {
    setHidden((o) => !o);
  }
return (
  ...
  ...
<div className="flex flex-col space-y-2">
            <label htmlFor="name">Password</label>
            <input
              type= {type}
              name="password"
              className="rounded-lg dark:bg-gray-700"
              value={form.password}
              onInput={[handleInput]}
              required
            /> 
            <Show when={form.password.trim().length}>
              <button 
                onClick={[toggle]}
              >
                <Show when={hidden()} fallback={<AiFillEye className="text-xl" />}>
                <AiFillEyeInvisible className="text-xl" />
              </Show>
              </button>
           
              
            </Show>
            
          </div>
```

When I test, it does display a button when I enter in the password field but when I click on this button, the type of this field does not pass from `password` to `name` yet I did use a ternary operator

Answer (score 2):

There is no input type `name`.

You should write `text` instead.

You can look input types from this [link](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_input.asp)

Comment: even when I use the text type, it doesn't change anything.

Comment: @Gouneken then the problem is your function call. You should look up how to call function inside the solidjs element or component.

Answer (score 0):

Input name is used for addressing an input field and is not what you are looking for. What you need is *type* switching between text and password however your logic is unnecessarily complicated and buggy since you are checking the type against the setter function.

You should start with password and toggle when user asks for it.

```js
import { render } from "solid-js/web";
import { createSignal } from "solid-js";

function App() {
  const [inputType, setInputType] = createSignal("password");
  const toggle = () => setInputType((curr) => (curr === "text" ? "password" : "text"));

  return (
    <div>
      <input type={inputType()} value="Some Value" />
      {` `}
      <button type="button" onClick={toggle}>
        {inputType() === 'password' ? 'show': 'hide'}
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}

render(App, document.getElementById("app")!);
```

Here is a live demo https://playground.solidjs.com/?hash=-364211793&version=1.4.1

Answer (score 0):

Heeey! I can provide another solution:

```
function Login() {
  const [hidden, setHidden] = createSignal(true);

  return (
    <div class="flex flex-col space-y-2">
      <label>Password</label>
      <input
        type= {hidden() ? 'password' : 'text'}
        name="password"
        class="rounded-lg dark:bg-gray-700"
        required
      />
      <button onClick={() => setHidden(!hidden())}>{ hidden() ? 'Show' : 'Hide'}</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```